# local host network monitor and httpservlet request

Tags: java, header, httprequest, network-monitoring

I have two Tomcat servers on my machine that communicate with one another.

1) Can someone recommend on a good (free) network sniffer so I'll be able to monitor the requests/ response that being sent between them?

2) How can I inspect the request in java code? to see what the header and the body consists and their structures?

thanks a lot, 
from some reason #2 is not as straight forward as i thought it would be.

Me

Comment: hi, 
sorry if it was not clear ... 
my question is "how can i print/see the header and the body of the request using java code"?

thanks

thanks

Comment: Did the servlet filter example below work for you ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Wireshark is "the" network sniffer.But if your on windows and want a quick and easy way to see http traffic have a look at Fiddler.Its an IE plugin but can monitor all http traffic from your machine.

2) In the servlet or better yet the servlet filter add the following.

```
Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
      out.println("<TR><TD>" + headerName);
      out.println("    <TD>" + request.getHeader(headerName));
    }
```

Comment: FWIW, Fiddler isn't really an IE Plugin.  It's a standalone proxy debugger. The only IE Integration it has is that it adds a button to IE's toolbar to launch it, but it does the same for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

If you're on Windows, you can't directly monitor the 127.0.0.1 loopback.  You will need to set up an alternate loopback adapter (the same functionality on another address).  This is detailed in the Wireshark docs:

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question, can you go into more detail?

If all your requests are HTTP-based, then Wireshark will be able to show the headers and body data, but it's outside the context of the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up the Tomcat servers for remote debugging for number 2? Add a break point so you can inspect the objects? http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

Comment: i have done it but i had troubles inspecting the request, that's what question number 2 about...

Answer (score 0):

I just used

http://socketsniff.nirsoft-freeware.qarchive.org/_download2.html

and it worked flawlessly for what I wanted.

Shamelessly copied from this question:

[Sniffer for localhost (Windows OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566234/sniffer-for-localhost-windows-os)