# Size or configuration limitation with perl's cgi script and apache

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I'm trying to find the problem with quite a big HTML-page generated through a Perl CGI-script.

My CGI script works as long as the generated webpage does not exceed 1 MB in size.

But as soon as the webpage exceeds one MB in size the page will display once correct in my browser, but after reload the page will be cut off at 1 MB.
The effect will remain for a while (>5 mins?) and then disappear for one reload.

I think I identified some possible sources for the problem:

- problem with perl's printing to `STDOUT`
- Apache limitation/bug
- configuration problem of Apache
- caching problem of the generated webpage
- something completely different

What I already tried:

- restarting Apache does not seem to change the duration to "one time healing".
- Perl's immediate flushing is enabled by `$|=1;`

Does anyone have a clue where the problem could lie?

Here is a test script with which I can reproduce the effect:

```
#!/Programme/perl/perl/bin/perl

$| = 1;

use strict;

use CGI qw/:standard -nosticky -debug/;   # CGI scripting
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # show error messages in browser
use CGI::Session qw(-ip_match);

my $cgi;

my $top   = 30;
my $i;

$cgi     = new CGI;

print <<EOF;
Expires: -1
Cache-control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="iso-8859-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-store">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

</head>
<body bgcolor="#efefef" text="#000000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
EOF

for ($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){

    # any popup_menu
    print $cgi->popup_menu(-name     => "monthSel$i",
                            -values   => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                            -default  => 1, 
                            -override => 1,
                            -style    => 'position:absolute; top: '. $top . 'px; left:50px'
                          );
    $top += 30;
}


# close body
print "</body>";
```

Comment: Two things that seem odd in your code: (1) why do you want 10.000 popups? and (2) there is no end html tag. Please try validating the html generated by this script and fix the validation errors before debugging any further.

Comment: You are right: (2) is true, but adding the html-tag does not change anything. But (1) is needed to generate a test page with more than 1 MB (3.000 popups would have been enough though - my original page would would have been far more complex).

Comment: Another thing: the generated html page (cgi execution through command line piped to a file) **can** be loaded correctly/completely in the Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I solved this issue, though I did not really find the root cause for this one.

Steps:

- When I tested it with a different system, everything was OK (at least the case with the 5000 popup menus).
- localhost itself did not work
- **but**: when forcing the packets through the regular network stack (originally for debugging with Wireshark, the page displayed correctly!

Conclusion: seems like an internal problem of the system

The way for forcing local packets through network stack was found here: [Sniffer for localhost (Windows OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566234/sniffer-for-localhost-windows-os) (use `http://localhost./` instead of `http://localhost/`)