# How to capture packets in localhost between two ports

Tags: sockets, network-programming, wireshark, inter-process-communicat

I have two applications communicating on same machine (localhost) using socket. If application are on different machine I can use Wireshark. But how to capture packets on same machine.

I do not know on which port number application are communicating. Because I am using library calls and do not know lower level details.

We are having our application on Ubuntu and Windows XP.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? For windows this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566234/sniffer-for-localhost-windows-os

Comment: @rene I need it for both OS. We are having our application on Ubuntu and Windows XP.

Comment: I added your comment to your question. Please check if that's ok with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux you can use [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to determine the ports that your application are using. Then you can use Wireshark to capture on the loopback interface (just enter your own IP address if 127.0.0.1 dont work).

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566234/ for capturing on Windows.

Comment: How does `netstat` capture traffic? Because that is what the OP asks.

Comment: He also asked "I do not know on which port number application are communicating ". He can use this to first determine which ports are being used, this can then ease the filtering on Wireshark