# How to configure client to catch local WCF requests in Fiddler?

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I have simple client app (console application) and server app (WCF library project) using WCF. I want to see how WCF messages looks like in Fiddler.

I added following code to client's app.config:

```
<configuration>    
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />      
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

My Fiddler shows all connections from browsers except one having word "vshub" in url, but there are no connections between WCF client/server apps displayed. How to configure it?

UPDATE1:

My WCF service library (server application) is configured in following way:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServer.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServer/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServer.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have nothing to do in the client config and you can remove your proxy settings. Fiddler will work if you do not use "localhost" and replace it with "MyMachineName"

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't matter. The OS is smart enough to map your machine name to localhost.

Comment: your server can listen on localhost, but change your client endpoint to your machinename like <endpoint address="http://mymachine/site/servicesvc" .....> and this is for fiddler...not for the system

Comment: excuse but the client config is not complete or ? can you add it

Answer (score 0):

Local requests aren't catched by Fiddler. Fiddler only catches requests that actually go over the wire. Local requests are shortcutted by Windows.

There is [an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066819/993547) with some alternatives, although I don't know how actual that list is.